# How to publish a library for both browser and Node using wasm-pack?

Tags: webassembly, wasm-bindgen, rust-wasm, wasm-pack

I'm writing a wasm library that I want to be available in both the browser and Node. Does this mean I need to run both `wasm-pack publish -t bundler` and `wasm-pack publish -t node`? Is there a way to publish both builds under the same package instead of publishing both `mylib-node` and `mylib-browser`?

This should be a fairly simple task (this library doesn't rely on any browser-specific stuff) but I've been unable to find a recommended example workflow.

Answer (score 2):

After investigating a bit, as this seems a natural feature, I found that this [issue](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-pack/issues/469) is [discussed](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-pack/issues/313) and [expected](https://github.com/PRQL/prql/issues/612) on the [wasm-pack github](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-pack), and there seems to be work done towards a `--target all` that would do exactly what you say, but we are not there now, apparently.

There were some suggestions that seemed to work, especially [this](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-pack/issues/313#issuecomment-441163923) script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

# Check if jq is installed
if ! [ -x "$(command -v jq)" ]; then
    echo "jq is not installed" >& 2
    exit 1
fi

# Clean previous packages
if [ -d "pkg" ]; then
    rm -rf pkg
fi

if [ -d "pkg-node" ]; then
    rm -rf pkg-node
fi

# Build for both targets
wasm-pack build -t nodejs -d pkg-node
wasm-pack build -t browser -d pkg

# Get the package name
PKG_NAME=$(jq -r .name pkg/package.json | sed 's/\-/_/g')

# Merge nodejs & browser packages
cp "pkg-node/${PKG_NAME}.js" "pkg/${PKG_NAME}_main.js"
sed "s/require[\(]'\.\/${PKG_NAME}/require\('\.\/${PKG_NAME}_main/" "pkg-node/${PKG_NAME}_bg.js" > "pkg/${PKG_NAME}_bg.js"
jq ".files += [\"${PKG_NAME}_bg.js\"]" pkg/package.json \
    | jq ".main = \"${PKG_NAME}_main.js\"" > pkg/temp.json
mv pkg/temp.json pkg/package.json
rm -rf pkg-node
```

Comment: And then does one just publish this with `npm publish`?

Comment: Yes, the combination should produce a publishable package, so `npm publish` should suffice. I didn't have time to test the script myself for now, though.

Comment: Note, the `jq` command isn't standard (at least on macOS)

Comment: tried @TachyonicBytes's code, and I am getting two issues with this command as-is. First, since my package uses a namespace, it fails. I adjusted the merge section to replace all instances of `${PKG_NAME}` with `${PKG_NAME##*/}`, which seems to fix that specific issue.

However, I still get `sed: pkg-node/mylib_bg.js: No such file or directory`